# lua traceback without message but with level

Tags: lua

Here is something fun:

```
-- file1.lua
require('./file2')

-- file2.lua
print("default:")
print(debug.traceback())
print("\n")

print("with both options:")
print(debug.traceback("prefix", 2))
print("\n")

print("nil message:")
print(debug.traceback(nil, 2))
```

This is what I get

```
default:
stack traceback:
        ./file2.lua:3: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        file1.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: ?


with both options:
prefix
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        file1.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: ?


nil message:
nil
```

So if I want to have a level, I MUST also include a message? How do I get this to work without providing a message?

Comment: Probably, it's a bug in Lua 5.1 (fixed in Lua 5.2).  As a workaround, an empty string may be used instead of `nil`

Comment: Ya but then the log would have a blank new line

Comment: That is the intended behaviour I guess.  At least the source has an explicit `return` when the message is not a string. https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/v5_1_1/ldblib.c#L333-L336  Same in LuaJIT actually https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/blob/61464b0a5b685489bee7b6680c0e9663f2143a84/src/lib_debug.c#L389-L393

Comment: @HenriMenke then I don't understand why they wouldn't allow developers to just provide the level without a custom message.

Comment: @Kousha That's a question you should ask on the Lua mailing list.